# What is this system icon that looks like a plus inside a diamond with three curved lines extending from its right side on Samsung?

Tags: notification-icons, samsung-droid-charge

My Samsung Droid Charge has an icon in my status bar that looks like a plus inside a diamond with three curved lines extending from its right side. It is the left-most icon in the right adjusted icons in the status bar of this home screen capture.

[image]

What is this icon for? Also, is there a setting where I can remove it?

Comment: it looks similar to the `gps` icon i've seen on other devices, have you checked your location settings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://cache.vzw.com/multimedia/mim/sam_charge/charge_manual.pdf) (WARNING: pdf file) for the phone (page 24), it is the GPS icon.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Of course, I should have RTFM. I did check out the Android 2.2.x PDF but didn't think to look at the manual for my actual phone.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [user manual](http://cache.vzw.com/multimedia/mim/sam_charge/charge_manual.pdf) (page 31 in my PDF viewer, actual page 24), that means your GPS is on/in use. You can check your system settings to disable location services (usually `Settings->Location and Security`).