# Is there a list of android system status bar icons?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, system, vanilla-android, notification-icons, vanilla-ui

I'm not sure what some of the status bar icons mean on my Android Nexus 5 device (I'm referring to the icons in top right of screen, adjacent to the time). I've googled frequently but I keep getting back a list of icons to use in app development.

I'm looking for a list of the system status bar icons and an explanation of the meaning of that icon. I'm interested specifically in the vanilla Android Lollipop OS on Nexus.

Comment: What kind of list do you want?

Comment: I assume you're after something like [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/12768/30530) but for stock Android 5.0?

Comment: @bmdixon - yes, exactly.