# List of icons for Moto G 2nd Generation running Android 5.0.2

Tags: notification-icons

I have a Moto G (2nd Generation) running Android 5.0.2.  I am new to both the device and to the Android OS, and would like to understand the meanings of the various notification icons present across the top of the home page of the device. Is there a list provided by Motorola or Google?

Note: I know about this related [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/what-is-this-system-icon-that-looks-like-a-plus-inside-a-diamond-with-three-curv/) but that link is specifically for a Samsung Droid Charge model, and is also dated.

Update: The link mentioned in the possible duplicate is a list of "suggested" icons from Google, and is not helpful.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no list of notification icons for every possible Android model. The best guide is Google's suggested icons for Lollipop system. Most of the icons are also self-explanatory. This makes the question too broad to be answered as of now. If you have particular icon in question, please describe and take a screenshot.

Comment: @AndrewT. That approach sounds more manageable, thanks. Just a side question: I am thinking that iPhone's icons are well-defined (although I don't know, I am not an iPhone user). If so, isn't this a weakness of Android against iPhone?

Comment: Well, that's because Apple has 100% control on iOS. Meanwhile, everyone can get Android source code and customize it. Whether it's a weakness or strength, I can't comment, though from what I see, most of icons on Android for core function are standardized.